# GCP Scheduler target http with url not working "INVALIDE ARGUMENTS"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow, scheduler, google-cloud-dataproc

I have created a **Dataproc Workflow Template** with no arguments that I want to schedule with Cloud Scheduler.
I take the same steps that was explained **https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/workflow-scheduler** and I test **the same example but it's not working**
This error with "invalid argument" appears and it's not clear.
This is what I have on the trace logging:

```
{ "targetType": "HTTP", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
"url": "https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/dev/regions/europe-west1/workflowTemplates/mytemp16:instantiate?alt=json", 
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", "jobName": "projects/dev1/locations/europe-west3/jobs/hello2" }
```

Comment: I tried replicating your error and I got it when I put some key value pair in the "Body". Just to confirm, when you were creating the scheduler job under "Configure the job's target" -> "Body". Did you just place `{}`?

Comment: Also make sure that you are using the same location of the dataproc template when creating the scheduler job. Can you try setting the location of the url under "Configure the job's target" to `europe-west1`?

Comment: I am living in france so i put the time zone of it in the configuration of the job. but still have the save error and i can't find it

Comment: yes i put {} in the body and it's not working too,

Comment: The docs that was provided is working as intended. Please double check your values in the URL (ex. Region, ProjectID, TemplateID). You may also reach out to [Google Cloud Platform Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub), if you have free trial or a support package, so that they could check this for you.

Comment: @najeh22 did you find the solution. I live in France also and i'm facing the same issue.